# Merging 2 or more text files after edit in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog, savefiledialog

Helo there!

it seems that i am facing a problem with my code in VB.net. Please be patient as i am a complete beginner in programming. I am trying to code a program that will load 2 or more txt files, find and exclude specific lines (starting with some characters or contain some characters) and then merge and save only one file that will contain all the information after the editing (from all the files).

I am using openfiledialog and i have set the multiselect to true. Below is the code for the OpenfileDialog:

```
        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        For Each File In OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
            My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        Next
```

If i am correct, it loads the filenames and reads all the text from the files. For the editing i am using the following code:

```
        Dim outputLines As New List(Of String)()
    For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadLines(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        Uline1 = line.StartsWith("text1")
        Uline2 = line.StartsWith("text2")
        Uline3 = line.StartsWith("text3")
        Uline4 = line.StartsWith("text4")
        Uline5 = line.StartsWith("text5")
        Uline6 = line.StartsWith("text7")
        Uline7 = line.StartsWith("sometext")
        Trash = line.Contains("^")

        If Uline1 Or Uline2 Or Uline3 Or Uline4 Or Uline5 Or Uline6 Or Uline7 Or Trash Then
            outputLines.Remove(line)
        Else
            outputLines.Add(line)
        End If
    Next
```

For the output i am using a savefiledialog with the following code:

```
    SaveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt"
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    SaveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
    If (SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, outputLines)
```

Although the files are being loaded correctly, the edit seems to happen only in one file (the last selected) and again the program saves only one file.

Could you please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to nest your loops through the file names returned by the open file dialog, and the lines returned by the `ReadLines` calls.  You also don't need to remove lines from the `outputLines` list, since they are never added.  Something like:

```
If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    Dim outputLines As New List(Of String)()
    For Each fileName In OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
        For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadLines(fileName)
            Uline1 = line.StartsWith("text1")
            Uline2 = line.StartsWith("text2")
            Uline3 = line.StartsWith("text3")
            Uline4 = line.StartsWith("text4")
            Uline5 = line.StartsWith("text5")
            Uline6 = line.StartsWith("text7")
            Uline7 = line.StartsWith("sometext")
            Trash = line.Contains("^")
            If Not (Uline1 Or Uline2 Or Uline3 Or Uline4 Or Uline5 Or Uline6 Or Uline7 Or Trash) Then
                outputLines.Add(line)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End If
```

If the files are very large you will start to run into memory issues, and will need to write the data out as it is read instead of keeping it all in memory.

**UPDATE**

Based on the comments, if you want to check the following line to determine if the current line should be written, you could use something like this.  Note the use of `ReadAllLines` and the `For` loop.

```
Dim outputLines As New List(Of String)()
For Each fileName In OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
    Dim lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
    For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Count - 1
        Dim line As String = lines(i)
        If line.StartsWith("19") AndAlso i < lines.Count - 2 AndAlso lines(i + 1).StartsWith("15") Then
            outputLines.Add(line)
            outputLines.Add(lines(i + 1))
            i += 1
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Thank you Mark I will give this a try... The files won't be more than 150kb each and maximum 20 files... I will let you know! Thanks again!

Comment: Hello Mark, i have tried the code above but i get a compile error: **Loop control variable cannot be a property or a late-bound indexed array** I have declared the fileName as string.

Comment: @Michael What is the line that gives the compile error. I did miss declaring fileName correctly, but you fixed that (I'll update the code), but I just pasted the code into VS and other than that I don't see an error once I declare the other variables (Uline*, etc).

Comment: Hello Mark, I have solved it already but thank you for the help... After testing, i found out that i need to keep a few lines but not in all the file. For example, how can i say in code: If a line starts with 19 and the next line starts with 15 write both lines... It should do this in all the files parsed.

Comment: @Michael In order to check the following line, you would need to modify the file reading and looping to use something indexable (`ReadLines` returns `IEnumerable(Of String)`, which would not be efficient to index).  See update above for one way.